# C++ Multidimensional Vectors Appending

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a 2D vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> world;
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
world[0][0] = x;
world[0][1] = y;
etc
```

So I came up with this function:

```
int Controller::AddBody(SDL_Rect RECT, SDL_Color COLOR)
{
    world[world.size() + 1].push_back(RECT.x);
    world[world.size() + 1].push_back(RECT.y);
    world[world.size() + 1].push_back(RECT.w);
    world[world.size() + 1].push_back(RECT.h);
    world[world.size() + 1].push_back(COLOR.r);
    world[world.size() + 1].push_back(COLOR.g);
    world[world.size() + 1].push_back(COLOR.b);
    world[world.size() + 1].push_back(COLOR.a);

    return world.size() + 1;
}
```

however this creates an exception. I can't understand why?

Comment: Because your vector is too small and you are accessing it out of bounds?

Comment: How do I make it bigger?

Comment: Well, `world.size()` as indexing would be already out of bounds; No wonder `world.size() + 1` is out of bound. But it shouldn't throw an exception.

Comment: You look up how to use a vector before you start using it blindly.

Comment: @juanchopanza I know how to use a vector, but not a multidimensional vector. `world.push_back(n)` does not work here.

Comment: A "multi-dimensional" vector is still a vector.

Comment: Well pushing it back throws an error with this multidimensional vector, whereas works with a normal vector.

Comment: There is no way `world[world.size() + 1]` can work.

Comment: @user3806521 wolrd.push_back(n) cannot work because you cannot push back an integer, when a vector of integer is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

world[world.size() + 1] will point off the end of the vector (one beyond world.end()).

Look back at what your world vector really represents: A vector of vectors.
So for each new entry in your world[] vector, you want to add a new vector.

The code should look like this:

```
int Controller::AddBody(SDL_Rect RECT, SDL_Color COLOR)
{
    std::vector<int> newVec;

    newVec.push_back(RECT.x);
    newVec.push_back(RECT.y);
    newVec.push_back(RECT.w);
    newVec.push_back(RECT.h);
    newVec.push_back(COLOR.r);
    newVec.push_back(COLOR.g);
    newVec.push_back(COLOR.b);
    newVec.push_back(COLOR.a);
    world.push_back(newVec);

    return world.size();
}
```

Keep in mind that when working with std::vector, the [] operator only allows access to an element that already exists in the array. So if your array is only 3 elements, and you try to set the 4th, you'll get an exception. You always have to either resize the vector or push a new element into the vector to create a new element.

Answer (score 2):

This is a more modern approach to the accepted answer utilizing the new [emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) methods added in C++11 and an [initializer list](http://ignoringthevoices.blogspot.ca/2011/11/c11-initializer-lists-and-range-for.html):

```
int Controller::AddBody(SDL_Rect RECT, SDL_Color COLOR)
{
     world.emplace_back(std::vector<int>{
        RECT.x, 
        RECT.y, 
        RECT.w, 
        RECT.h, 
        COLOR.r, 
        COLOR.g, 
        COLOR.b, 
        COLOR.a
    });
    return world.size() + 1;
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/557f8103b5c1ac20)

Comment: That gives me the error `could not deduce template argument for '_Valty &&' from 'initializer-list'`

Comment: @user3806521 See [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550924/emplacement-of-a-vector-with-initializer-list/24551018#24551018).